# BigQuery table from dataframe

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I would like to create a bigQuery table for genomic data with Google Datalab notebook and hitting the columns limit. The table is created from pandas `DataFrame`.

```
# to communicate with Google BigQuery
from pandas.io import gbq
gbq.to_gbq(df_pgp_input, 'pgp_orielresearch.pgp_PIK3CA_all_ml', 'speedy-emissary-167213', chunksize=10000, verbose=True)
```

> GenericGBQException: Reason: invalid, Message: Too many fields: 12427

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#import), the max limit for total columns in Bigquery is 10000.

That's why for the most part it's better if you arrange your data using [ARRAYs and STRUCTs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#arrays_and_structs) as you won't hit these quota limits.

Comment: Alas, adding STRUCT's won't help, since 10000 limit is on total of leaf fields, regardless of structure.

Comment: Hi @MoshaPasumansky, I wonder if OP creates an ARRAY with STRUCTS for each column and aggregates by some key if it would work fine. For what I tested here, I could create ARRAYs with 100k STRUCTs quite easily (instead of creating 10k keys inside of a struct, creating an array with a struct for each column, for each row).